# Unknown argument in GraphiQL trying to pass an ID from the client to the GraphQL server?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Im using Apollo 2. With the GraphiQL interface I can run a query which returns all groups fine. However when I try to pass a name to find just 1 group it doenst work.

Schema

```
type Query {
    hi: String
    groups: [Group]
    group(name: String): Group
}

type Group {
    name: String
}
```

Resolvers:

```
Query: {
        hi() {
            return 'howdy';
        },
        groups() {
            return Groups.find().fetch();
        },
        group(one, two, three) {
            console.log('group resolver called');
            console.log(one, two, three);
            //return Groups.findOne(two.name);
        },
    },
```

This is my GraphiQL groups query which works fine:

```
{
  groups {
    name
  }
}
```

But my group query returns an error:

```
{
  group(name: "some name") {
    name
  }
}

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"group\" of type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 9
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE - This is my full file:

```
import { createApolloServer } from 'meteor/apollo';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import merge from 'lodash/merge';

import GroupsSchema from '../../api/groups/Groups.graphql';
import GroupsResolvers from '../../api/groups/resolvers';

const typeDefs = [GroupsSchema];
const resolvers = merge(GroupsResolvers);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

createApolloServer({ schema });
```

In resolvers.js

```
import Groups from './groups';

export default {
    Query: {
        hi() {
            return 'howdy';
        },
        groups() {
            return [{ name: '1', test: 'test 1' }, { name: '2', test: 'test 2' }];
            // return Groups.find().fetch();
        },
        group(one, two, three) {
            console.log('group resolver called');
            console.log(one, two, three);
            // return Groups.findOne('Apon9HKE9MeZqeXsZ');
        },
    },
};
```

In Groups.graphql

```
type Query {
    hi: String
    groups: [Group]
    group(name: String): Group
}

type Group {
    name: String
}
```

Comment: Did you try change 'group(one, two, three)' to 'group(name)' at your resolver?

Comment: Ive tried group(root, { name }) and group(name). I get the exact same error message.

Comment: Can you add the all content of your file? Resolvers and Schemas?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança Done.

Comment: I think that should be group(root, { name }), but you've told that doesn't work. Why are you importing the groups schema at resolvers?

Comment: Are you using graphql-tools? Take a look to this site: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your typeDefs and resolvers are wrongs, try:

typeDefs

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hi: String
    groups: [Group]
    group(name: String): Group
}

type Group {
    name: String
}`;
```

Resolvers

```
export default {
        Query: {
            hi() {
                return 'howdy';
            },
            groups() {
                return [{ name: '1', test: 'test 1' }, { name: '2', test: 'test 2' }];
                // return Groups.find().fetch();
            },
            group(_, { name }) {
                console.log('group resolver called');
                console.log(one, two, three);
                // return Groups.findOne('Apon9HKE9MeZqeXsZ');
            },
        },
    };
```